# Call an imported Function in app.get(/) in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, routes

Can I call an imported function in `app.get("/")?` is it good practice?

Does this also mean that all logic must be done in the `addArticle` function?

`post.js`

```
const addArticle = async post => {
 const postData = {
  body: post.body,
  title: post.title,
  username: post.username
 };
 const { data } = await axios.post(
  `${BASE_URL}/data/`,
  postData
 );
 return data;
}
catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const postfunc = require (./post.js)
const app = express()

app.get("/", post.addArticle)

app.listen(3001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s acceptable to pass your route handler however you see fit. However, your `addArticle` function doesn’t conform to express [route handler signature](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Your function should handle two arguments, being express.Request and express.Response instances respectively.

Finally, note that returning a value from a route handler does nothing — if you want to send that value to the client, you’ll need to use `res.send` or similar method.